# I want my header and side menu to remain unchanged while I navigate to another page like facebook

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want my page to load the header and side menu once and they may remain reload when I navigate to another page . I need to know how facebook does it at the same time what libraries and languages are needed to execute such a task

```
/*main page*/
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Feedback</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/22_64.png" type="image/x-icon" sizes="32x32"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script>
    function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
    function submitForm(){

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body id="feedback_body">
    <?php include_once("header.php"); ?>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
     <?php include_once("side_menu.php"); ?>
     <?php } ?>
    <div id="for_feedback">
    <table width="" height="auto" style="background-color:orange; width:100%; color:#fff; font-size:20px;"><tr><td style="height:40px; width:auto; text-align:center;"><b>Please let us any problem you find.</b></td></tr></table><br />
    <form id="my_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
      <div style="float:left;"><input style="width:240px; height:28px; border-radius:3px;" id="n" placeholder=" Name" required>
      <span><input style="width:240px; height:28px; border-radius:3px;" id="e" placeholder=" Email Address" type="email" required></span></div>
      <br /><br /><br />
      <textarea id="m" style="width:793px; border-radius:4px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; box-shadow: inset 2px 2px #888888;" placeholder=" Describe your problem here" rows="10" required></textarea>
      <div style="float:right; margin-right:5px;"><span id="statuser"></span><input id="mybtn" class="feedback_btn" type="submit" value="Send"></div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    /*Header*/

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/22_64.png" type="image/x-icon" sizes="32x32"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/search.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="dialog2.js"></script>
    <header id="header">
        <div id="logo">
          <a href="home">
            <div id="main_ico"></div>
          </a>
          </div>

          <div id="logsign">
              <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    if($numrows400 < 1){
        echo "&nbsp;".$feedback."&nbsp;".$changepwd;

        }
        else{

        echo "&nbsp;".$feedback."&nbsp;".$changepwd;
        }

        include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");

        $sql71 = "SELECT * FROM online WHERE onlineuser='$log_username'";
    $query71 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql71);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query71);
    if($numrows < 1){
        $sql70 = "INSERT INTO online(onlineuser, lastcheck) VALUES('$log_username',now())";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql70);
    }else
    {
        $sql70 = "UPDATE online SET lastcheck=now() WHERE onlineuser='$log_username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql70);
    }

              }
                  ?>  &nbsp; &nbsp; <?php echo $loginLink; ?>

              </div>



              <div id="home">
              <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
              <a href="home">
                <img src="images/home.png" height="32" width="32"alt="home" title="Home">
              </a><?php } ?>
              </div>

              <div id="home">
              <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
                <?php echo "<a title=".$log_username." href=".$log_username.">".$user_top."</a>"; ?>
              <?php } ?>
              </div>

              <div id="home">
              <!--&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="feed.php">Feed</a>-->
              <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
              <a href="all_groups"><img src="images/group3.png" alt="groups" border="0" title="Groups" ></a>
    <?php } ?></div>
                <div id="home">
              <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
                <?php echo $messager; ?>
              <?php } ?>
              </div>
    <form class="search" action="search" id="search" method="get">
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
        <input name="searchquery" type="text" size="44" placeholder="Search..." maxlength="88" required />
        <?php } ?>
    </form><span id="statuses">checking...</span>
    <div id="home_2">
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    if($numrows400 < 1){
        echo $notedrop;
        }
        else{

        echo $notedrop1; }
          } ?>

          </div>

            </header>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

    /*side menu*/

    <div id="main_panel">
    <ul style="list-style:none;">
    <a href="h" style="color:#CCC;"><li id="sub_panel"  <?php if ($thisPage == "h"){?> class="active" <?php }?>><b>H</b></li></a>
    <a href=<?php echo $le; ?> style="color:#CCC;"><li id="sub_panel" <?php if ($thisPage == "u"){?> class="active" <?php }?> ><b>P</b></li></a>
    <a href="i" style="color:#CCC;"><li id="sub_panel" <?php if ($thisPage == "i"){?> class="active" <?php }?> ><b>M<?php echo $messer ?></b></li></a>
    <a href="n" style="color:#CCC;"><li id="sub_panel" <?php if ($thisPage == "n"){?> class="active" <?php }?> ><b>N<span id="panelnoti"><?php echo $noter ?></span></b></li></a>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <ul>
    <a href="a" style="color:#CCC;"><li id="sub_panel" <?php if ($thisPage == "g"){?> class="active" <?php }?>><b>G [<?php echo $g_check; ?>]</b></li></a>
    </ul>
    <div style="max-height:230px; min-height:100px; overflow-y:auto;">
    <?php echo $mg; ?>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <ul style="list-style:none;">
    <a href="b" style="color:#CCC;"><li id="sub_panel" <?php if ($thisPage == "b"){?> class="active" <?php }?>><b>R</b></li></a>
    <a href="p" style="color:#CCC;"><li id="sub_panel" <?php if ($thisPage == "p"){?> class="active" <?php }?>><b>P</b></li></a>
    <a href="s" style="color:#CCC;"><li id="sub_panel" <?php if ($thisPage == "sphp"){?> class="active" <?php }?>><b>S</b></li></a>
    <a href="t" style="color:#CCC;"><li id="sub_panel" <?php if ($thisPage == "t.php"){?> class="active" <?php }?>><b>T</b></li></a>
    <a href="l" style="color:#CCC;"><li id="sub_panel"><b>L</b></li></a><br />
    </ul>
    <code style="color:#CCC;">&copy; 2016</code>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like frames :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A `SPA`, or `Single Page App`, can well serve your demand. Why not see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)?
- As for facebook, it is not an SPA, but here is [a post](https://www.quora.com/Is-Facebook-a-single-page-application-If-not-then-how-arent-the-chat-and-sidebar-refreshed-from-page-to-page) about it. In brief, it uses `ajax` to fetch data so there is no page refresh.

Hope it works! Have a good day!